# Measure Theory: Prove that $\mu( \cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}B_k)=1$ given $\mu(B_k)=\mu(B)=1$, $B_k \subset B$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

> **Problem:** For a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ with measure $\mu: \mathcal{A} \to [0, \infty]$  
>  Let $B \in \mathcal{A}$ and $(B_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{A}$ be a sequence such that $B_k \subset B$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. 
> Prove that if $\mu(B)=\mu(B_k)=1$ for all $k$ then $\mu( \cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}B_k)=1$

---

**My approach**: It doesn't take much effort to show that $$ \mu \left(  \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B_k\right) \leq 1 $$
Because certainly: $$\bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B_k \subset B_k \text{ for every } k \in \mathbb{N} \implies \mu \left(  \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B_k\right) \leq \mu(B_k)=1 $$ because the measure $\mu$ is monotone.

**My problem** is the less obvious inequality, namely $$  \mu \left(\bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B_k \right) \geq 1 $$

I haven't made use of the fact that $\mu(B)=1$ but I also don't believe that $$\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B_k = B $$ is true.

Any hints for the missing inequality? The problem at hand clearly being that $\cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B_k$ cannot easily be approximated from below, thus the only possible way might be to bring the strict inequality $$ \mu \left( \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B_k \right)< 1 $$ to a contradiction.

Comment: Hint: $$\mu\left(\bigcap_k B_k\right)=\mu(B)-\mu\left(\bigcup_k (B\setminus B_k)\right)\geqslant\mu(B)-\sum_k\mu\left(B\setminus B_k\right)$$

Comment: Thanks @Did, with the given identity $$ \mu \left( \bigcup (B \setminus B_k) \right) \leq \sum \mu (B \setminus B_k) = \sum \mu(B) - \sum \mu (B_k)=0 $$ using only sigma additivity and differences of measurable sets. It follows immediately that $$ \mu \left( \bigcap B_k \right) \geq \mu (B)=1 $$ I now must confess that I have no idea where your identity comes from, do you have a reference?

Edit: I confused the geq/leq

Comment: A reference? What for? Instead compare $B$ and $$\left(\bigcap_kB_k\right)\cup\left(\bigcup_k(B\setminus B_k)\right).$$

Comment: Given $A \subset B$ I always have $B= A \cup (B \setminus A)$, specialising this for my case that $A = \bigcap_K B_k \subset B$ and using De Morgan's law I obtain your identity. Thanks for your assistance.